# django ValueError Cannot query "abcd@gmail.com": Must be "object" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i am trying to make an app for student but i'm getting this error,
as you can see for convenient i wanted to use like that one i showed bellow but it doesn't work, should i keep using like before? or i could use like that ? what would be best way ?

**ValueError at /student/program_structure/
Cannot query "abcd@gmail.com": Must be "Student" instance.**

thank you so much :)

```
models.py

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
          settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS, default='active')
 
 
class Program(models.Model):
        
         #everything was fine when used 

    user = models.ForeignKey(
          settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  #this one

         #but when using this one i started getting this error from views.py 

    user = models.ForeignKey(
                  Student, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Course(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)

   subject = models.ManyToManyField('Subject', related_name='subject_list', 
                  blank=True)


views.py
       

class Program_structure(generic.View):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = get_object_or_404(Student, user=self.request.user)
        program_structure = Course.objects.filter(student=profile)
         # program_structure = 
        Course.objects.filter(student__user=self.request.user)


        credit = Course.objects.filter(student__user=self.request.user).
           annotate(total_no=Sum('subject__credit'))

        total_credit = self.request.user.course_set.aggregate(
             total_credit=Sum('subject__credit')
           )['total_credit'] or 0

     context = {
        'test':program_structure,
        'credit':credit,
        'profile':profile,
        'total_credit' : total_credit
    }
    return render(self.request, 'program_structure.html', context)
```

Comment: Please show your `Course` model

Comment: i have added can you please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user` field of the `Course` refers to the `Student` object, not a `User` object, so you can not user `request.user` for this.

You can however query for a `Course` where the `user` is a `Student` where the `user` is `request.user` with:

```
class Program_structure(generic.View):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = Student.objects.all()
        program_structure = Course.objects.filter(user__user=self.request.user)
        context = {
           'test':program_structure,
           'profile':profile,
        }
        return render(self.request, 'program_structure.html', context)
```

You probably also want to set `profile` to the `Student` object of the user. In that case, you can *reuse* the `profile` when you filter the `Course`s:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class Program_structure(generic.View):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = get_object_or_404(Student, user=request.user)
        program_structure = Course.objects.filter(user=profile)
        context = {
           'test':program_structure,
            'profile':profile,
        }
        return render(self.request, 'program_structure.html', context)
```

It might also be better to rename the `user` field to `student`:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        Student,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    # …
```

since that makes it clear that this is a `Student`, not a `User`. In that case you filter with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class Program_structure(generic.View):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = get_object_or_404(Student, user=request.user)
        program_structure = Course.objects.filter(student=profile)
        context = {
           'test':program_structure,
            'profile':profile,
        }
        return render(self.request, 'program_structure.html', context)
```

Comment: AttributeError at /student/program_structure/
'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'course_set'  sir im now getting this error you remember, you did solve that :) can you please check i have edit views.py how do i solve that ?

Comment: @Rafikhan: that is below the retrieval of the course, instead of `total_credit = self.request.user.course_set.aggregate(...)`, you use `total_credit = program_structure.aggregate(...)`.

Comment: this is amazing, you could publish a book, we can learn from you sir. traditional books tutorial really doesn't talk about those issue, thank you so much. looking for your advice how could get better in django,python

Comment: sir i have got a question, can you please check that out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64476658/updateview-in-django